# How to make a element in .bindpopup accessible for external functions in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a function that feeds variables to a Popup, which is working so far. Now I inserted a button in this Popup and want some function to run when clicked on this, but the  the object is not accessible for my external function. How can I rewrite this function, to access the single elements more easy?

marker:

```
var marker      = L.marker([data[i].lat, data[i].lng], {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(map);
marker.bindPopup(id + "<br>" + species + "<br>" + diameter + "<br>" + quality + "<br>" + damage + "<br>" + notes + "<br>" + "<br>" +
'<input type="submit" id = "delete" name="action" data-value = " + id + " value="Delete" method = "post"/>');
```

function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#delete').click(function(d){
            
        alert("deleted")
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: where is the implementation that you describe up to this point? I only see a marker and a popup to bind to this marker in your current code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the listener after the Popup is opened:

```
marker.on('popupopen',function(e){
    $('#delete').click(function(d){ 
        alert("deleted")
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have figured out, what you provide to `bindPopup` in your code is just an HTML string that you cannot directly use to attach an event listener to.

You have several possible solutions for this:

- build an HTML Element to [pass to `bindPopup`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#popup-setcontent) instead of a String, so that you can manipulate it as an object
- defer the attachment of your listener to after the popup is open, hence the HTML string is converted to a DOM element on the page
- use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to attach your listener to a parent element instead, which already exists in DOM, but filtering events to target your future button

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

With jQuery this could be like:

```js
$("body").on("click", "#delete", myListenerFunction);
```